# File Not Found Error Django

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm new to django and I'm trying to make a web app. I have a running back end, but the problem is it's only running on cli and I have to turn it into a web app.

```
def testing(request):

    ksize = 6
    somsize= 10
    csvname="input.csv"
    testcap = "testing.pcap"
    pl.csv5("chap/a",testcap)
    tmparr=[]
    for filename in os.listdir("chap"):
        if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
            tmparr.append(filename)
            continue
        else:
            continue
    tmparr.sort()
    visual_list = natsort.natsorted(tmparr)
    csv = sl.opencsv(csvname)
    norm = sl.normalize(csv)
    weights = sl.som(norm,somsize)
    label = sl.kmeans(ksize,weights)
    #for x in range (2,21):
    #   label = sl.kmeans(x,weights)
    #  print("K is", x, "Score is ", label[1])
    lblarr = np.reshape(label,(somsize,somsize))
    #sl.dispcolor(lblarr)
    classess = sl.cluster_coloring(weights,norm,csv)
    classpercluster = sl.determine_cluster(classess,lblarr,ksize)
    classpercent = sl.toperc(classpercluster)
    print (classpercent)
    #print(classpercluster)
    for x in visual_list:
        temp = ("chap/"+x)
        tests = sl.opencsv(temp)
        print(tests)
        hits = sl.som_hits(weights, tests)
        name = ("img/" + x +  ".png")
        sl.disp(lblarr,name,hits)


    return render(request,'visualization/detail.html')
```

The system cannot find the path specified: 'chap', I'm not sure if I should put the chap folder inside the templates folder or in the app folder. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Pass the full path name for the file instead of a relative name.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing relative paths here it looks like. Change it to an absolute path.

```
dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
chap_dirpath = os.path.join(dirpath, chap_dirpath)
```

Comment: I tried that but I need to access the /a in the folder.

Comment: Can you post an example of your project structure?